# Print Using Modem and Printer Through BTS

Tags: c#, printing, embedded, sms

In my scenario to print something, I don't want the printer has to be connected with a computer. Rather I am trying to connect that with a Modem(GSM or any other). 
 when a sms arrives to the modem, the print command will fire and the sms will be printed.
[image]
My question is, **is it possible to implement the diagram with our existing technology?** If not, i will be delighted if you provide some alternatives.

Comment: How would you attach a GSM modem to a printer?

Comment: USB or any latest technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you can customize the firmware of the GSM modem or the printer, it is likely you will need a small computer in between.  If both can talk over serial ports, this can be really tiny - PIC, AVR (including packaged version such as Arduino), etc.  If at least one needs USB you may be better off with a bare-metal Arm board.  This is going to range from $2 at the low end to maybe $70 at the high.  (There are also a few Arm boards that run an embedded .NET framework if that is your background... how well they run it I'm not sure)

If you need to do formatting, or the printer depends on the computer to do a lot of the work, or your engineers aren't familiar with the mindset of tiny embedded systems, you probably want something capable of running an operating system - ie, a faster Arm chip with hundreds of megabytes of memory - think Beagleboard, plugputer, Chumby Hacker Board, etc or one of those micro-servers that are basically x86 netbooks refactored for better cooling.  Depending on how careful you are, this puts you anywhere from $50-$250.

You could also use an android phone (pick one with known USB host capability) and fold in the GSM capability, but may spend a lot of time tripping over the android components when all you really want is an embedded linux with a full libc.  A more "linux-y" linux smartphone might be preferable if you can find one you expect will continue to be available.

Comment: It's an awesome and very complete answer :)

Comment: I would only add that some printers have WiFi and that for some a Java environment is simpler than an embedded Linux with libc. An Android phone with a Java program which sends a PCL or Postscript or PDF job to a WiFi enabled printer may also be feasible.